# Is WSO2 JAVA 8 ready?

Tags: java, wso2

I utilize the WSO2 ESB, App Server, and Data Services modules.  We are being forced to move off of JAVA 7 and upgrade to JAVA 8.  Does anyone have any information on if WSO2 is compatible with JAVA 8?  Thanks!

Comment: AFAIK, we haven't tested our products in JDK 8 yet

Comment: Thank you very much for your response Ratha!

Comment: Java 6 ran out of public update last year, java 7 in going to next year.  Java 8 needs to get moved up in the priority list quickly.  I've identified problems with Java 8 as of right now.

Answer (score 2):

All the WSO2 products which are based on carbon kernel 4.4.0 or higher version supports Java 8. At the moment following WSO2 products are been released with the Java 8 support.

- Governance Registry  5.0.1
- Business Process Server  3.5.0
- Machine Learner  1.0.0
- Complex Event Processor  4.0.0
- Application Server   5.3.0
- Enterprise Store 2.0.0
- Enterprise Service Bus   4.9.0
- Governance Registry  5.0.0

You can refer to [WSO2 Release Matrix](http://wso2.com/products/carbon/release-matrix/) to check the latest WSO2 product releases.

Answer (score 2):

WSO2 ESB 4.9.0 will not work with java 8 in a windows environment although they say it supports java 8. We were told it would but after weeks of trying, we had a video conference with their support team and they realized the issues we were having was with java 8.

The issue we were having was the proxy service would quit working. After starting ESB, I would run a soapUI request. If I went more than 1 minute without running a request again, the service would stop working. My soapUI request would simply spin and never return a response. We would restart the ESB service and my soapUI request would work again but with the same timing issue.

They had me reinstall java 7 and the issue went away. They've created a jira ticket on their end to look into the problem while we continue to use java 7 at this time.

Answer (score 1):

For now we are supporting up to only JDK 1.6 to build our source. But you can run our products using up to JDK 1.7. We still testing further to support up to latest version.

Answer (score 1):

I use WSO2 ESB 4.9.0 and Java 8, I do not have any problems. I use soap proxy and JMS proxy, and also use SOAP UI with it. I did not run on problems such as stopping working. I can put Windows 10 to hibernate, next day open it and proceed sending JMS and Web service requests.